# How to recover from The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable. error?

Tags: bash

I added these lines to my `.bashrc` file:

```
export vertx_home=/anto/vertx/bin
export PATH=${PATH}:${vertx_home}/bin
```

after doing that. I get an error message like that for all command's I run, for example:`clear`,`groovy` :

```
Command 'clear' is available in '/usr/bin/clear'
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
clear: command not found
```

How to recover from it?

I'm new to Ubuntu. Kindly help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: run echo $PATH and see what is in path variable

Comment: it shows `${PATH}:${VERTX_HOME}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two points:

1. No need for the first 'export' command
2. Looks to me you have got your vertx_home set wrong, as your effective path is: /anto/vertex/bin/bin - note the repetition of 'bin'

Suggest changing your .bashrc to read as follows:

```
vertx_home=/anto/vertx 
export PATH=$PATH:$vertx_home/bin
```

Close any open terminals for the change to take effect.

Comment: The problem is that I couldn't able to open `vi ~/.bashrc` as it says the same error in my original question. Not only `vi`, many other commands got struck-ed!

Comment: Where I can find that file manually?

Comment: Have you tried using the full path of editor and file? Something like `/usr/bin/gedit /home/YOUR_USER_NAME/.bashrc`

Answer (score 1):

vi is in
`/usr/bin/vi`
try `/usr/bin/vi ~/.bashrc`